# jquery fadeIn, fadeOut problem: fadeIn second part of <h1> not working properly

Tags: jquery

I have an `<h1>` with text `first part of titel` that should be faded in, then after a delay, the second part of the title should be faded in so the title looks like `first part of titel second part of titel`.

I can't figure out how to solve this programmatically. I tried callbacks, `promise()` but I can't make it work.

Here is the last working code I have:

```js
const $this = $('h1');
const $span = $('h1 span');
$this.delay(700)
  .fadeOut(0, () => {
    $this.html('First part of<br>text');
    $this.css("color", "#000");
  })
  .fadeIn(500)
  .delay(4000)
  .fadeOut(0)
  .fadeIn(500, () => {
    $this.html('First part of<br>text second part of text');
  })
  .delay(5000)
  .fadeOut(500, () => {
    $this.html('A different text');
    $this.css("color", "#000");
  })
  .fadeIn(500)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1><span></span></h1>
```

jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/0m4z59xe/

Comment: Does this updated fiddle work?
https://jsfiddle.net/dnkp6eba/

Comment: The problem here is, that the text is being faded out, before being faded in again with the second text added to it. The first text should fade in - stay - delay - second text faded in. But thanks for your input. Without fading your code would be a simple solution in fact.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a span for every part that you want to fade in or fade out. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28720555/jquery-word-for-word-fade-in-effect) you can find an example of what I mean.

```
var fadeInterval = 300

$('h1').html(function(_, txt){
    var words= $.trim(txt).split(' ');
    return  '<span>' + words.join('</span> <span>') + '</span>';
}).find('span').each(function(idx, elem){        
    $(elem).delay(idx * fadeInterval).fadeIn();
});
```